# JsDoc: Remove "static" tag from property

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have graph constructor written in JavaScript. The documentation is a bit borked. Below is the part of my code and the documentation which does not work as I want:

```
function Graph() {
    ....
    var nodes = [];
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        /**
         * An array of all node handles in the graph
         *
         * @return {Array}
         */
        nodes: {
            get: function() {
                var ids = [];
                for (var id in nodes) {
                    ids.push(id);
                }
                return ids;
            }
        }
    });
    ....
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to make sure the graph can't be manipulated using other means than the methods provided by giving a copy of the node list, not the actual node list.

This works well, but in the JsDoc, it is defined as static:

```
<static>    Graph.nodes
            An array of all node handles in the graph
```

Now, this property is not static. It is individual for all instances of graphs. My guess is that JsDoc recognizes the definition of the `nodes` property to be inside `Object.defineProperties()`, and claims that all declarations inside here are static.

Is there a way to tell JsDoc that this property is in fact not static? I could only find the tag `@static`, which does the exact opposite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is @instance, see the [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-instance.html)

// Edit: Working example

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Graph() {
    var nodes = [];
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        /**
         * An array of all node handles in the graph
         * @return {Array}
         * @memberof Graph
         * @instance
         */
        nodes: {
            get: function() {
                var ids = [];
                for (var id in nodes) {
                    ids.push(id);
                }
                return ids;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and hope, that answers question more thoroughly. Version 3.3.0 of JSDoc produces the intended output.

Comment: Still did not work, but may very well be because of outdated version. I have 2.4.0. Will update and test again

Comment: Updating it did the trick! In addition to fixing it, the generated documentation looks much better! Thanks!